# How do I use a yaml selector?

Tags: dbt

I am experimenting with yaml selectors, so far without success.  My selectors.yml:

```yaml
selectors:
  - name: daily
    description: selects models for daily run
    definition:
      exclude:
        - union:
            - "tag:pp_backfill"
            - "tag:inc_transactions_raw_data"
            - "tag:hourly"
```

And when I try to use it I get an error:

```
$ dbt ls --selector daily
* Deprecation Warning: dbt v0.17.0 introduces a new config format for the
dbt_project.yml file. Support for the existing version 1 format will be removed
in a future release of dbt. The following packages are currently configured with
config version 1:
 - honey_dbt
 - dbt_utils
 - audit_helper
 - codegen

For upgrading instructions, consult the documentation:
  https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/migration-guide/upgrading-to-0-17-0

* Deprecation Warning: The "adapter_macro" macro has been deprecated. Instead,
use the `adapter.dispatch` method to find a macro and call the result.
adapter_macro was called for: dbt_utils.intersect
Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
  Could not find selector named daily, expected one of []
```

I tried this in both 0.18.1 and 0.19.0, with and without `config-version: 2`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be as simple as `electors` on that first line instead of `selectors`?

Comment: Hi Claire, no.  I missed a character when I copy pasted into SO, but the file itself has `selectors` :). Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the blocker here might be that you are not currently selecting anything initially *to then* exclude specific models from using the tag method.  Here is solution in my project and then an adoption that might work in your case.

#### Context

I'm running dbt version 0.19.0 on dbt Cloud.  Both of these compiled and successfully ran `dbt run --selector daily`.

#### Jaffle Shop Example

`stg_customers` is tagged with `dont_run_me` and `stg_orders` is tagged with `also_dont_run_me`

`selector.yml` is the following at the root of the dbt project

```
selectors:
  - name: daily
    description: selects models for daily run
    definition:
      union:
        - method: path
          value: models
        - exclude:
            - method: tag
              value: dont_run_me
            - method: tag
              value: also_dont_run_me
```

The logic here is that I'm first select **all the models** and then exclude the union of the models that have tags `dont_run_me` and `also_dont_run_me`.

`dbt run --selector daily` ended up running everything in my project *except* `stg_customers` and `stg_orders`

#### Specific Case

If you are trying to select all models except for ones that are tagged as `pp_backfill`, `inc_transactions_raw_data`, and `hourly`, I think the following will do the trick:

```
selectors:
  - name: daily
    description: selects models for daily run
    definition:
      union: 
        - method: path
          value: models
        - exclude:
            - union:
               - method: tag
                 value: pp_backfill
               - method: tag
                 value: inc_transactions_raw_data
               - method: tag
                 value: hourly
```